# Would you use Cassandra for aggregate queries?

Tags: database, elasticsearch, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

Has anyone used Cassandra in production, for data aggregates of many millions of rows accross multiple regions ?

Example:
A worldwide seller, say Amazon for example

Data columns : 
user, postcode, item_purchased, amount , datetime, country

Say i want a query which :
Get me the total amount spent per postcode per item per country.

Would Cassandra even be a bad choice for this kind of aggregation ?

What would you use ? Would it be something like Elasticsearch ? A RDBMS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick answer: No :)

Cassandra doesn't support rich SQL queries. Technically Cassandra has some aggregations but this functionality is very limited.

There are several ways to do aggregation if your data is too large for RDBMS.

1. NoSql storage + query engine. You can store data in Cassandra, Hbase or even in files on S3 and use such software like Hive, Spark SQL or Apache Drill for executing complex SQL queries on NoSQL storage.
2. Elasticsearch now has a rich functionality for making aggregations.
3. If you are on AWS the relatively simple and cheap solution is to put your data on S3 in Parquet format and use Athena to do aggregations.